# javascript to get an attribute from an array based on a url parameter

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to filter a json array based on a value from a url and get the `vernacularName` attribute.
In the F12 debugging I can put `record[0].vernacularName;` and it gives me the correct variable, but still the below code fails.

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = datasetID;` works but `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vernacularName;` does not.

Ultimately I want to add vernacularName as a session variable

```
<body>
  <div class="">
    <h3>testing data</h3>
  <p id="demo" class = 'pl-5'></p>    
  </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

  const species = urlParams.get('species')
  const bone = urlParams.get('bone')

  const datasetID = urlParams.get('datasetID')

  var data;
  $.getJSON("json/data.json", function(json){
    data = json;
  });

  record = data.filter(r => r.datasetID == datasetID);


  var vernacularName = record[0].vernacularName;
  // const vernacularName2 = record.vernacularName;
  $_SESSION["v"] = vernacularName;


</script>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vernacularName;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not sure why

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vernacularName;
```

is within in its own `script` tag. That seems quite odd.

In any case, the issue here is that the data is not ready yet. You can't start to process the data & use it to update elements on the page until the data has been returned to you.

That's the whole point of the second argument to `getJSON` - its a function called upon success, *after* the data has been fetched.

Hence, the rest of your code should all go inside that function:

```
  $.getJSON("json/data.json", function(json) {
    const data = json;
    const record = data.filter(r => r.datasetID === datasetID);
    const vernacularName = record[0].vernacularName;
    $_SESSION["v"] = vernacularName;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = vernacularName;
  });
```

**Side note:** Since it appears you're using ES6+, then you shouldn't be using `var` unless you have a good reason to. Use `let` instead. There's information about it [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) post. However, in this case, everything in your code is constant, so stick to `const`.